# QtSql (from PyQT) seems to be broken

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt4, qtsql

I cannot access mysql server (on localhost).
Python 3.1 & latest PyQt

my code:

```
from PyQt4 import QtSql
db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")
db.setHostName("localhost")
db.setDatabaseName("test")
db.setUserName("root")
db.setPassword("admin")
db.open() #this always returns true. why?
```

P.S. I'm beginer.

Comment: no errors, but db.open() always returns false

Comment: there should be an error if it doesn't open. Post up what QSqlDatabase::lastError() (http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qsqldatabase.html#lastError) method returns after you try opening your database

Comment: >>> db.lastError().driverText()
'Driver not loaded'

how should I fix it?

Comment: I'm not a mySQL guru but it looks like you need to enable mySQL support for QT: take a looks here http://www.pikopong.com/blog/2009/07/22/how-to-enable-mysql-support-in-qt-sdk-for-linux/ and here: http://www.pikopong.com/blog/2010/04/11/how-to-enable-mysql-support-in-qt-sdk-for-windows/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It always returns True, or it always returns False? Make up your mind.

Anyway, the docs says:

> Opens the database connection using
>   the current connection values. Returns
>   true on success; otherwise returns
>   false. Error information can be
>   retrieved using lastError().

So if it always returns False, that's because it couldn't open the database. Call db.lastError() to have it tell you why.